# Why was this question not migrated to Movies and TV?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, migration

[This question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/104077/was-dr-octavius-brine-inspired-by-octodad) about the Penguins of Madagascar movie was closed as off topic for this site but seems like it should be on-topic for Movies and TV.

Why was this question not migrated?

Comment: I don't know why, but it's too late to migrate it now.

Comment: @anaranjada there is a time limit?

Comment: 60 days or so. If you flag/vote to close something older than that and select "off-topic", it will say "too old to migrate".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**It's a moot point now.**

The question could indeed have been migrated to Movies & TV, but none of the close-voters, nor the OP himself, ever flagged it for migration. I don't know why they didn't, but at this point the post is more than 60 days old and therefore cannot be migrated. It's stuck on the SFF site forever now.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I wasn't aware of the time limit for migration.

Comment: ...neither was I. I'll choose my flag reasons more carefully. "With much power," and all that....

Comment: And what, *you* didn't read their minds and migrate it yourself? tsk tsk tsk Rand!

Comment: @Mooz Hey, I wasn't a mod back then! By the time I got elected, it was already too late to migrate that question.

Comment: @Rand was joking :)

Comment: Poor question..

Comment: @AnkitSharma The OP is still around; you could ask him if he wants to repost on M&TV?

Comment: It currently has four reopen votes, so the point may become even moot-ier.

Comment: @Randal'Thor I will love to but now that questions fate is more complicated after reopen votes.

Comment: It's now reopened and I flagged it for migration (I don't know the process, hope that was at least semi-appropriate).

Comment: @MeatTrademark Thanks, but unfortunately this answer still holds: the question is more than 60 days old and therefore can't be migrated.

Comment: Oh, right. That was rather stupid of me. I read this stuff and knew that, and still managed to screw it up. I guess I just got turned around by Ankit's "I will love to but now that questions fate is more complicated after reopen votes" comment (I know I read it out of context.). And I jumped without thought. Should/can I vote to close again as it really does seem to be off-topic? Is there a rule about that? I screwed up, plain and simple.

Comment: @Randal'Thor [done](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/104077/was-dr-octavius-brine-inspired-by-octodad#comment323001_104077)

Comment: @MeatTrademark It's possible to re-VTC as long as you didn't VTC the first time round (it doesn't matter that you VTROed). And you were only one of five VTROs, so don't worry about screwing up :-)

Comment: Do we know that this question is off topic? Was it reopened in a vain hope of migrating, or because someone thought it should stay open here? Maybe @AnkitSharma knows.

Comment: @anaranjada Some of the VTROers probably did so because they thought it was on-topic, and at least one did so in a vain hope of migrating. As for whether we "know" it's off-topic ... well, *I* certainly don't, as I know nothing about Penguins of Madagascar. Feel free to open a new meta question about whether it should be closed or not.

Comment: @anaranjada What is scifi and what not.....mmmmm......i don't know. But it was closed and then opened after this meta post ( including me who is confused now) and one user did commented that he reopend it for migration  possibility. For the rest 3 i don't know. I even posted the close vote again to reverse my previous decision and now it have 4 cv

Comment: @AnkitSharma I only asked because it listed you as one of the reopeners. That question seems like an edge case that could play a part in the Scope Wars.

Comment: @anaranjada Yeah i think i shouldn't have reopened it in first place as i don't know the border lines which is blurry to me. Maybe it's another meta post time ;)

Comment: @AnkitSharma You could, but I'm trying to stay neutral in the Scope Wars. The Tag War is enough for me.

Comment: My hands are pretty much stuck in other stuff too. But will love to see clear picture.

Comment: @Randal'Thor Better to update the answer with current status.

Comment: @JonSnow What current status? As far as I can tell, the question is still here on SFF and this answer still applies.

Comment: @Randal'Thor First it was here because it was too late and now it's here because it was made on topic, anyway nevermind.

Comment: @JonSnow The fact that it's a moot point is still valid regardless of whether or not the question is on-topic here.